# Stop MySQL From Recalculating Previous Rows

Tags: php, mysql, loops, limit

I have an import script that has to import ~500,000 records from and old system of mine to my new one, but the import requires a bit of PHP processing (for field validation mostly, such as phone numbers, so I cannot use MySQL to do my processing).

Two things I need are the ability to watch the progress of the import, and for the PHP script not to run out of memory (so I can't just select all the rows at once).

So I've accomplished this by creating a resolution variable and a counter that increases (sort of like a page for paginating data) that will grab the first `$Resolution` amount of rows, do the processing, import the rows to the new system, and then loop back around and grab the next set of rows.

Now the problem lies when I have:

```
select `Column` from `table` where `Something`=1 limit 0, 1000;
```

That takes say, 5 seconds. But so now on the next loop I have:

```
select `Column` from `table` where `Something`=1 limit 1000, 2000;
```

Which takes 10 seconds because it has to recalculate the rows from the first loop to be able to get the next set of rows. As you can see, this gets super slow super fast, so I would I go about this without incurring the extra calculations from previous loops?

Comment: what do you mean by 'recalculate the rows from the first loop'? btw if you want to grab the next 1000 rows, then your second query should end in `limit 1000, 1000`

Comment: The way the `limit` works, it has to figure out what rows preceded it, and so it's basically re-selecting all of the rows before the beginning of the `limit`, so it's technically building 2000 rows the second time, but I'm only fetching the last 1000

Comment: If there is an index on the `Something` column, it can speed up the process.

Comment: the database already optimizes `limit offset` queries. the syntax is `limit x, offset y`, so your 1st query actually selects 0 rows - which is why it's fast. a limit, offset query doesn't make sense w/o an `order by`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an `ORDER BY xxx` clause, with an index on the `(Something, xxx)` columns.

A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` really has no value here since you would have no control over which rows will appear in each set.

Comment: The order by killed the performance of even the first query, and I definitely have indexes on the column being used. I may have found a solution though that this inspired me to come up with. Is there anything wrong with setting a new `Index` column from 1 and up and using `where \`Index\`>1000 and \`Index\`<=2000` instead?